# How to get database size via TDBXReader?

Tags: mysql, delphi

I'm trying to get the size of my database via TDBXReader. My command SQL return two lines, the my database size and sum of all database sizes.

I'm trying to use Reader.Value[0] to get the value of sum of database and get error TDBXTypes.BCD value type cannot be acessed as TDBXTypes.Doubletype.

If I use Reader.Value[1] get 'Invalid Ordinal = 1'

The function:

```
function ChangeBD() : double;
var
  Con : TDBXConnection;
  Cmd : TDBXCommand;
  Reader :  TDBXReader;
begin
  Result:= 0;
  Con := TDBXConnectionFactory.GetConnectionFactory.GetConnection('mydb', 'root', 'root');
  Cmd := Con.CreateCommand;
  Cmd.Text := 'SELECT Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024 "BDsize" FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '+quotedstr('mydb');

  Reader := Cmd.ExecuteQuery;

  if Reader.Next then
    begin
      Result:= Reader.Value[0].GetDouble;
    end
  else

  Con.Free;
  Cmd.Free;
  Reader.Free;

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How can you expect a 2nd value (`Reader.Value[1]`) you get when you put only one data field (`"BDsize"`) for disposal?
- Use`GetAsDouble`
- Do a test `if Reader.Value[3].AsString >''` you can not convert a **empty** value to a double
- with `if Reader.Next then` you will get only 1 row from many! Use `while` instead

---

With following `SELECT` you get 4 Columns

- table_name , [0]
- data_length , [1]
- index_length , [2]
- total_size , [3]

---

```
var
sum : double;

[...]

Cmd := Con.CreateCommand;
Cmd.Text := 'SELECT table_name, '+
            'round( data_length / ( 1024 *1024 ) , 2 ) data_length, '+
            'round( index_length / ( 1024 *1024 ) , 2 ) index_length, '+
            'round( round( data_length + index_length ) / ( 1024 *1024 ) , 2 ) total_size '+
            'FROM information_schema.TABLES '+
            'WHERE table_schema = ''mydb'' ';

Reader := Cmd.ExecuteQuery;
```

GetAsDouble

```
function ChangeBD() : double;
[...]
while Reader.Next do
   begin
    if Reader.Value[3].AsString > '' 
       then sum := sum + Reader.Value[3].GetAsDouble;
   end
Result:= sum;
```

Or do your own sum;

```
function ChangeBD() : double;
[...]
while Reader.Next do
   begin
    if Reader.Value[3].AsString > '' 
       then sum := sum + StrToFloat(Reader.Value[3].AsString) ;
   end
Result:= sum;
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and explanation. GetAsDouble will be help me.